# Jquery search for a value inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the  following div,

```
<div class="clinic_visit_list_entry animated fadeInUp">
    <div>Hepatitis B</div>
    <div>Screened: Yes</div>
    <div>Treated: Yes</div>
    <div>Referred: Yes British American Tobacco Kenya Clinic</div>
</div>
<div class="clinic_visit_list_entry animated fadeInUp">
    <div>Hepatitis B</div>
    <div>Screened: Yes</div>
    <div>Treated: Yes</div>
    <div>Referred: Yes British American Tobacco Kenya Clinic</div>
</div>
```

When I select a value from the  following html select tag ,

```
<label>Select Service</label>
<select class="select_with_label" name="Service" id="select_service">
    <option selected="selected">Please select</option>  <option value="TB">TB</option>
    <option value="Hepatitis B">Hepatitis B</option>
    <option value="Hepatitis C">Hepatitis C</option>
    <option value="Overdose management">Overdose Management</option>
    <option value="Abscess">Abscess</option>
    <option value="Alcohol & drug abuse">Alcohol & drug abuse</option>
    <option value=" Cervical cancer" >Cervical cancer</option>
</select>
```

It should trigger the  following jquery :

```
$("#select_service").change(function () {
     var value = $( "#select_service" ).val();
     //Search through the Div for the selected value 
});
```

Which should search through the  clinic visit entry list if the  selected value exists in the div. How can I implement the  search through the div? (It should only search for the  values which are already in the  select option values)

Comment: Search thru and then do what?

Comment: @lshettyl then it alerts if the  value already exists in the  Div , example if it finds Ascess in the  div , it should alert you that it already exists in the  div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could loop through all the divs and check if their content matches the selected value.

```
$("#select_service").change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $(".clinic_visit_list_entry div").each(function() {

        if ($(this).text().match(value)) {
            //Text found in div 
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [**`:contains`**](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector

> **Description**: *Select all elements that contain the specified text.*

```
$("#select_service").change(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    var div = $('.clinic_visit_list_entry div:contains("'+value+'")');
});
```

[**JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ly2ce7wh/)

[Demo with an `alert`](http://jsfiddle.net/Ly2ce7wh/1/) (OP comment to the question)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend searching through the data that produced the HTML markup for the `div`, but if you must search the DOM you could use [jQuery's `find` method](https://api.jquery.com/find/). A complete, working example is below.

```js
$("#select_service").change(function () {
  var value = $( "#select_service" ).val();
  
  //Search through the Div for the selected value
  var isFound = !!$('div.clinic_visit_list_entry').find('*:contains(' + value + ')').length;
  var output = document.createElement('div');
  
  output.innerHTML = 'Value ' + value + ' found: ' + isFound;
  document.body.appendChild(output);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="clinic_visit_list_entry animated fadeInUp"><div>Hepatitis B</div><div>Screened: Yes</div><div>Treated: Yes</div><div>Referred: Yes British American Tobacco Kenya Clinic</div></div><div class="clinic_visit_list_entry animated fadeInUp"><div>Hepatitis B</div><div>Screened: Yes</div><div>Treated: Yes</div><div>Referred: Yes British American Tobacco Kenya Clinic</div></div>

<br />

<label>Select Service</label>
<select class="select_with_label" name="Service" id="select_service">
  <option selected="selected">Please select</option>  <option value="TB">TB</option>
  <option value="Hepatitis B">Hepatitis B</option>
  <option value="Hepatitis C">Hepatitis C</option>
  <option value="Overdose management">Overdose Management</option>
  <option value="Abscess">Abscess</option>
  <option value="Alcohol & drug abuse">Alcohol & drug abuse</option>
  <option value=" Cervical cancer" >Cervical cancer</option>
</select>

<hr />
```